# Why am I getting undefined appending to the page, but I can get data in the console?

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, undefined

So I am trying to append data from a .json file that was provided for me. However, instead of the information showing on the page. Well "undefined" is appending to page and console.

I am doing a lot of testing console logs and debuggers. So I have gotten the actually object or data in the console.

Also I would like to share the json file I was given, but it won't fit here. As it exceeds the character amount. So I have only shared a part of it.

This is JS file

```
$("button").click( function(){
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.0.6:8080/posts.json", function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(items, info) {
        // console.log(info);
        $("div").append("<p>" + info.item_data + "</p>");

      }); //end loop
    }); //end ajax
  } //end button on click
);
```

Here is html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title> Like Pinterest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">  <!-- hold it together with this main container -->
      <div id="divsocial">
        <p>

          <!-- the json data -->
        </p>
      </div>
      <button type="button" name="button" id="button">Oh Hai</button>
      <!-- <button type="button" name="button" id="button">Load More</button> -->
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal@3.3.2/dist/scrollreveal.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

.JSON file:

```
{
    "items": [{
            "item_id": "497",
            "item_data": {
                "image_id": 226,
                "text": "Seen on the catwalks at Chanel, Ralph Lauren, and Topshop Unique; think luscious icy bright pastels to add a soft pop of colour to the dull winter months. It works beautifully against grey tailoring and comes in a variety of textures from sugar plum boucle to cashmere soft duck egg blue\u2026",
                "link": "http:\/\/www.bullring.co.uk\/news\/fashion\/aff-edit-new-pastels",
                "link_text": "Click here to explore the trend.",
                "image_url": "http://placehold.it/600x350"
            },
"account_data": "",
            "item_source_id": "e3d89e1f295f72b85737d5067ac52e6c",
            "service_id": "5",
            "account_id": "3",
            "category_id": "1",
            "item_name": "Manual: Seen on the catwalks at Chanel, Ralph Lauren",
            "item_status": "published",
            "item_created": "2014-08-29 11:50:14",
            "item_imported": "2014-08-29 11:50:14",
            "item_published": "2014-09-10 10:06:59",
            "account_name": "AFF",
            "account_slug": "manual",
            "account_group": "",
            "account_order": "0",
            "account_status": "active",
            "account_item_default_status": "published",
            "account_import_interval": "2592000",
            "account_last_imported": "2014-06-01 00:00:00",
            "account_next_import": "2020-01-01 00:00:00",
            "account_created": "2014-08-28 11:38:45",
            "account_updated": "2014-08-29 09:09:18",
            "service_name": "Manual",
            "service_slug": "manual",
            "service_class": "Manual",
            "category_slug": "pinned",
            "category_name": "Pinned"
        }
}
```

So, what I want JS to execute would look something like this:

```
<div class="container">  <!-- hold it together with this main container -->
      <div id="divsocial">
        <p>
          <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" alt="" /><br />
          <span>
            Seen on the catwalks at Chanel, Ralph Lauren, and Topshop Unique; think luscious icy bright pastels to add a soft pop of colour to the dull winter months. It works beautifully against grey tailoring and comes in a variety of textures from sugar plum boucle to cashmere soft duck egg blue\u2026
          </span> <br />
          <a href="http:\/\/www.bullring.co.uk\/news\/fashion\/aff-edit-new-pastels">
Click here to explore the trend</a>
        </p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't append the entire object you'll have to append each of the key value pairs separately .

```
$("button").click( function(){
$.getJSON("http://192.168.0.6:8080/posts.json", function(data) {
  $.each(data.items, function(items, info) {
    // console.log(info);
    $("div").append("<p>" + info.item_data.text + "</p>" + "<a href=" + info.item_data.link + "> + info.item_data.link_text +</a>");

  }); //end loop
}); //end ajax
```

} //end button on click
);

Comment: You are correct! Thank you so much. I'll will continue to practice.

Answer (score 1):

Run foreach loop over `data.items` instead of `data` as `data.items` is the array

```
$("button").click( function(){
    $.getJSON("http://192.168.0.6:8080/posts.json", function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(items, info) {
        // console.log(info);
        $("div").append("<p>" + info.item_data + "</p>");

      }); //end loop
    }); //end ajax
  } //end button on click
);
```

And since `info.item_data` is not a string but an Object, so you may get `[object Object]` in the paragraph. I think you are making some mistake and instead of `item_data` you mean something else

Comment: You are right, I have tried that at some point. I get `[object Object]` on the page, in 2 paragraphs. And yes `item_data` is in correct. It should have showed above as `info.items` or something like as the start to show where I am in all this.

And thank you so far! I am still fiddling with it. Nothing yet with the solution you have shown me.

Comment: Oh I mean that for some reason it's doubling in paragraph form `[object Object]`. So like I have for some reason 2 paragraphs, `[object Object]`.

Comment: Please show the desired HTML that you want after JS execution

Comment: I hope I understood you correctly. I put the desired JS execution at the top.

Comment: I am not about JS execution but rather the HTML that you want after the AJAX gets complted

Comment: What I posted is what I am looking for when the HTML get's compiled. I would like the actually .json data to appear on the page. All of it, and after I plan to break it down for each div.